# How to use SVG icons with Syncfusion components such as ContextMenu?

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion's [Angular Context menu component](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/context-menu/getting-started/). I was looking at [this demo](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/?_ga=2.240041216.2036178189.1634308595-1276050562.1634308595#/material/context-menu/default) and wanted to add my own icons to the component. How to add icons is by adding CSS classes.

```
public menuItems: MenuItemModel[] = [
    {
        text: 'Cut',
        iconCss: 'e-cm-icons e-cut'
    },
    {
        text: 'Copy',
        iconCss: 'e-cm-icons e-copy'
    }
];
```

This is not sufficient for me because [the icon set they provide](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/appearance/icons/) is extremely limited. How can I add my own SVG icons to the ContextMenu component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve your requirement using iconCss property. Please refer below code snippets.

```
public menuItems: MenuItemModel[] = [
    {
        text: 'File',
        iconCss: "custom-icon file",
        items: [
            { text: 'Open' },
            { text: 'Save' },
            { text: 'Exit' }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: 'Edit',
        items: [
            { text: 'Cut' },
            { text: 'Copy' },
            { text: 'Paste' }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: 'View',
        iconCss: "custom-icon cal",
        items: [
            { text: 'Toolbar' },
            { text: 'Sidebar' }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: 'Tools',
        items: [
            { text: 'Spelling & Grammar' },
            { text: 'Customize' },
            { text: 'Options' }
        ]
    },
    { text: 'Go' },
    { text: 'Help' }
];

@import "../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/styles/material.css";
@import "../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-navigations/styles/material.css";

.file {
    background-image: url(image/file.svg);
}

.custom-icon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 4px;
}

.cal {
    background-image: url(image/calendar.svg);
}
```

For your reference, we have prepared a sample:

Link: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/my-app-18175361521317925097

Comment: I am assuming you are from the syncfusion support team. Thank you for responding with such detail.

Comment: path doesn't work in monorepo @M.Azyoksul